# Any differences between The Avengers releases?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, alternate-version

This weekend, Marvel's re-releasing *The Avengers* into theaters in the US.  At the moment there's little information on whether this release is identical to the original release.  Many blogs are taking the text of the release to suggest there's some new footage post-credits, but when I read it, it just seems like they're pointing people to not miss the shawarma [scene](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=427199330671412&set=a.229675623757118.60886.126757470715601&type=1):

> Marvel’s The Avengers is back in theaters for Labor Day Weekend!
>
> Don’t forget to stay through the credits and enjoy your shawarma!

Is this re-release identical to the original release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got back from a showing, and it's the same release as before.  No new footage, no new post-credits sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, there seemed be some subtle differences in the sound and several short reaction shots early on that I don't remember from previous viewings.  All my previous viewings have been Regal or AMC, this is the first time I have seen it at Cinemark.  Their different sound system may be making me imagine differences that aren't there.

If there are differences, it only adds up to a total of 1 or 2 minutes through the whole movie.